# Direct product of two normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, normal-subgroups

> Let $A$ and $B$ be normal subgroups of a group  $G$ such that $A \cap B = \langle e \rangle$ and $AB = G$. Prove that $A \times B \cong G$

*Attempted proof:*

Define $f : A \times B \rightarrow G$ by $f(a,b) = ab$. From a proof of another exercise, the hypothesis of this problem implies $ab = ba$. Therefore, $f(a,b) = f(b,a)$.

Since $f((a,b) \cdot (c,d)) = f(ac, bd) = (ac)(bd) = a(cb)d = a(bc)d = (ab)(cd) = f(ac) f(bd)$ for $a,c \in A$ and $b,d \in B$, it follows that $f$ is a homomorphism.

Now I need to show that $f$ is bijective (so show both injectivity and surjectivity of $f$), so that $f$ is an isomorphism from $A \times B$ to $G$.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Should be $f(ab, cd) = ab \cdot cd = f(a, b) \cdot f(c, d)$. Everything else sounds ok

Comment: Fixed the error. My bad.

Comment: Ops I meant $f(a, c) \cdot f(b, d)$. I guess you are assuming $a, b \in A$ and $c, d \in B$

Comment: Yes, that too ($a,b \in A$ and $c,d \in B$).

Comment: What do you mean by "the hypothesis of this problem implies $ab=ba$"? The group certainly does not have to be abelian. Also $f(a,b)=f(b,a)$ doesn't mean anything, since $f$ is defined on $A\times B$, not on $B\times A$. And again, $f(ac)$ is even worse, since $f$ is a map of two elements, not one.

Comment: @glacier That's actually where you need to use the fact if $A$ and $B$ are normal then $ac = ca$ for each $a \in A$, $c \in B$. So you should add more passages: $$f(ab, cd) = ab \cdot cd = a \cdot bc \cdot d = a \cdot cb \cdot d = ac \cdot bd = f(a, c) \cdot f(b, d)$$

Comment: @ChristophPegel There was a whole other problem I asked here on math.SE a few days before. It addressed that the hypothesis implies $ab = ba$ (or rather in that problem, $kn = nk$).

Comment: So you mean $ab=ab$ for all $a\in A, b\in B$. Should have said what $a,b$ are. Now you still have the problem of $f(b,a)$ and $f(ac)$ being meaningless expressions.

Comment: You say that $f(ac, bd) = \cdots = f(ac) \cdot f(bd)$, but neither $f(ac)$ nor $f(bd)$ are defined, since $f$ takes two arguments (in contrast, for instance $f(ac, e)$ and $f(e, bd)$ are defined). What you want to show, however, is that $f(ac, bd) = f(a, b)\cdot f(c, d)$. _That_ would make $f$ a homomorphism. You have done that, but the formulation is not so fortunate.

Comment: On another note, to be precise you should write $f((a,b)\cdot(c,d)) = f(ac, bd) = \cdots = f(a,b) \cdot f(c,d)$. Using the definition of the group operation in $A\times B$ in the first step.

Comment: @glacier, I elaborated on the problems you have for the proof of $f$ being a homomorphism in my updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Hints:** You will need $AB=G$ to prove surjectivity and $A\cap B=\{e\}$ to prove injectivity.

---

Since you still didn't fix the issue with $f(b,a)$ and $f(ac)$ being meaningless expressions, let me elaborate on this:

You want a homomorphism $f:A\times B\to G$, so you can put a pair $(a,b)\in A\times B$ in $f$ an get some element $f(a,b)\in G$.

- Writing $f(b,a)$ for $b\in B, a\in A$ implies you could put a pair $(b, a)\in(B\times A)$ in $f$, which is not the case, since $f:A\times B \to G$, $\color{red}{\text{not }f:B\times A\to G}$.
- Writing $f(ac)$ for $a,c\in A$, thus $ac\in A$, implies you could just put an element of $A$ in $f$, which is not the case, since $f:A\times B\to G$, $\color{red}{\text{not }f:A\to G}$.

What you want is for $(a,b), (c,d) \in A\times B$ to have
$$ f((a,b)\cdot(c,d)) = f(a,b)\cdot f(c,d),$$
where by definition of the operation in $A\times B$ we have $(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=(ac,bd)\in A\times B$.
Now you suggest to define $f$ as
\begin{align}
f : A\times B &\longrightarrow G, \\
(a,b) &\longmapsto ab.
\end{align}
Using this definition, we can evaluate both sides of the equation we want to prove for $f$ to be a homomorphism:
\begin{align}
f((a,b)\cdot(c,d)) &= f(ac, bd) = acbd, \\
f(a,b)\cdot f(c,d) &= ab\cdot cd = abcd.
\end{align}
Now, since $c\in A$, $b\in B$ where $A,B$ are normal in $G$ and $A\cap B=\{e\}$ you conclude from your previous problem that
$$
acbd = a(cb)d = a(bc)d = abcd.
$$
Put everything together and you obtain
\begin{align}
f((a,b)\cdot(c,d)) &= f(ac, bd) = acbd = a(cb)d \\&= a(bc)d = abcd = ab\cdot cd = f(a,b)\cdot f(c,d).
\end{align}

Comment: he didn't ask for hints...

Comment: @dani_s I'm still working this problem out on paper, so actually, hints like this one are helpful. :)

Comment: @glacier still, if you didn't ask for hints then no hints should be given!

Comment: @ChristophPegel I am trying to do injectivity right now. If $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, then $ab, ba \in A \cap B$. But $A \cap B = \langle e \rangle = \{ e \}$. So $ab = ba = e$, and so $f(a,b) = f(b,a) = e$. Somehow, because we have two things that equal the same thing (in this case, the identity $e$), I seemingly disproved injectivity... so I'm gonna (hopefully) see where I went wrong.

Comment: What you have to prove is that if $f(a, b) = f(c, d)$ then $(a, b) = (c, d)$

Comment: Can I say $f(a,b) = f(c,d)$ implies $ab = cd$. Now, this implies $a = c$ and $b = d$, because, WLOG, $ab = e$ (from the fact that $ab \in A \cap B = \langle e \rangle$) so that $(a,b)= (c,d)$?

Comment: @glacier No, because $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ doesn't imply $ab \in A \cap B$

Comment: I think you're wrong in your first two comments, @dani_s . Hints are a perfectly valid, important and educative way to push askers towards the proof of their question. Whether the OP asked or not about hints is irrelevant: even if the OP asked for complete answers and *not* hints the usual trend in this site is **not** to give complete, whole answers to questions. More than that is expecting someone else to do your work for you. Many (I think most) members of this site would strongly disagree with this.

Comment: @DonAntonio, I think dani_s point was that OPs question was just on how to prove $f:A\times B\to G$ is a homorphism, not yet about it being bijective, whereas I just gave hints on how to prove bijectivity in my original answer. (Though I already discussed the other problems in the comments)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps more succint and going the other way around (easier, imo):

$$G=AB\implies \forall\,x\in G\;\;\exists\,a_x\in A\,,\,b_x\in B\;\;s.t.\;\;x=a_xb_x$$

Now, if also $\;x=a'_x+b'_x\;,\;\;a'_x\in A\;,\;\;b'_x\in B\;$ , then we'd have that

$$a_xb_x=a'_xb'_x\implies a'^{-1}_xa_x=b'_xb_x^{-1}\in A\cap B=1\implies\;\ldots$$

and we get injectivity of $\;G\to A\times B\;$ defined by $\;x\mapsto (a_x,b_x)\;$

Surjectivity is trivial, of course.