# Why $G=HK$ and $H\cap K=\{e\} \implies G = H\times K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, direct-product

Given that $G$ is finite abelian, in order to show that $G = H\times K$ one only needs to show that $G=HK$ and $H\cap K=\{e\}$. What motivates this and why is it only true for finite abelian groups?

Comment: In general, if $G = HK$ and $H \cap K = \{e\}$ and $H$ and $K$ are both normal in $G$, then $G = H \times K$. Normality is automatically satisfied in any abelian group.

Comment: I would say $ G =HK \simeq H \times K $

Comment: Regarding Bungo's comment see: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690951/direct-product-of-two-normal-subgroups

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let define: $$\varphi:\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}H\times K & \rightarrow & G\\(h,k) & \mapsto & hk\end{array}\right.$$
$\varphi$ is a group homomorphism, since $G$ is abelian and your assumptions imply that $\varphi$ is bijective. Indeed, if $hk=e$, then $H\ni h=k^{-1}\in K$.

Going further:

> **Proposition.** Let $G$ be a group and $H,K$ normal subgroups of $G$. If $H\cap K=\{e\}$, then: $$H\times K\cong\langle H\cup K\rangle.$$

One derives the:

> **Corollary.** Let $G$ be a finite group. If all Sylow's subgroups of $G$ are normal, then $G$ is isomorphic to the direct product of its Sylow's subgroups.