# Properties of $S_{6}$ subgroups

Tags: group-theory

the question is as follow:

> 1) $H \lt S_{6}$ of order 9. prove that H is not cyclic.
>
> 2) $A \lt S_{6}$ of order 16. prove that A is not abelian.

so for 1) I know that $H$ is abelian but can't so therefore it's isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/3 \mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/3 \mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Z/9 \mathbb Z$ both are cyclic so what am I missing?

about 2) I have no sense of direction.

Thank you!

Comment: $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z\,\times \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ is not cyclic!

Comment: Hint (for the first part):  any permutation breaks up into disjoint  cycles and the order of the permutation is the lcm of the orders of the cycles.

Comment: Yes I thought about about that. taking two disjoint 3-cycles and then the order is 9.

Comment: No, if you take two disjoint $3$ cycles the order is $3$.

Comment: Oh! so there's no breaking the cycles to form lcm of 9

Comment: There's no breaking of _anything_. LCM of 3 and 3 is 3.

Answer (score 1):

The first question follows from the fact that all Sylow $3$-subgroups of $S_6$ are isomorphic to $C_3\times C_3$, which is *not* cyclic, see the comment. The order of a $3$-Sylow subgroup in $S_6$ is $9$, because $6!=5\cdot 3^2\cdot 2^4$.
Now $C_3\times C_3$ is such a Sylow subgroup, but every other Sylow $3$-subgroup is conjugated to it, hence isomorphic.

The second question goes similarly, with Sylow $2$-subgroups.

Comment: Would you care to summarize the proof? Other wise, it seems you are asking the OP to take your word, with no proof, and only a link to a potential proof.

Comment: @dietrich-burde in the exam the say that $H=<\sigma \tau>$ and that $<\sigma> \cap <\tau> = {e}$ hence $H = <\sigma> \times <\tau>$ from a theorem I've learned there's a requirement that $gcd(<\sigma>, <\tau>)=1$ for that, and that doesn't apply here.

Comment: No, there is no such requirement, see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1564792/why-g-hk-and-h-cap-k-e-implies-g-h-times-k).