# A Question About Direct Products of Groups

Tags: group-theory

Is the converse of the proposition [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690951/direct-product-of-two-normal-subgroups) true?
I can prove that that there exists two subgroups of G that satisfy the hypothesis but I can't prove that they are A and B. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: By "converse," do you mean: "if a group $G$ satisfies $G\cong A\times B$ for some groups $A$ and $B$, then there exist normal subgroups $H\cong A$ and $N\cong B$ of $G$ such that $H\cap N=\{e\}$ and $HN=G$"? If so, yes, the converse holds (and is easier to prove than the other direction).

Comment: Yes. Can I further show that they are in fact A and B?

Comment: That sounds like a philosophical question.  Some people just say two groups are equal if they are isomorphic.  After all, the category of groups doesn't really "see" each group individually, but rather the isomorphism classes of groups.  But some rigorous mathematicians will denounce the usage of the word "equal" to mean "isomorphic."  So, the answer to your comment can be both *yes* and *no*.

Answer (score 0):

If $G$ is isomorphic to $A \times B$, there is an invertible homomorphism of groups
$$\phi: G \to A \times B$$
Pick the two subgroups $\phi^{-1}(A)$, $\phi^{-1}(B)$ of $G$. They are (of course) isomorphic to, respectively, $A$ and $B$, and satisfy the hypothesis of the proposition (they are normal, intersect trivially and their product is $G$).