# Isomorphism between normal subgroups

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

I'm trying to work out this group theory proof:

Suppose that $G$ is a group have that has a normal subgroup $H$ such that $H$ is isomorphic to $D_3$. Prove that exists a subgroup $K$ of $G$ such that $G$ is isomorphic to $H\oplus K$.

Here is what I was thinking:

I was thinking $K$ could be the centralizer of $H$ in $G$. Because then we know that $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ since $H$ is normal. Then I was thinking that there would be a relationship between a group $G$ and the direct product of two normal subgroups, however I'm not really sure how to build on that.

Also I was wondering how we can use the fact that $H$ is isomorphic to $D_3$, because I can't really understand how that would help.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690951/direct-product-of-two-normal-subgroups

Possibly related?

Comment: no it inst, because this question doesn't assume that the intersection is trivial or that HK = G

Comment: This is a special case of a general fact: a complete normal subgroup is a direct factor see the part on extensions here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_group.

Answer (score 2):

Let $H \cong D_3$ and $K = C_G(H)$ (centralizer of $H$ in $G)$. Then $G/K \cong A \le Aut(D_3)$, $K \trianglelefteq G$.

Here you have to prove that $|Aut(D_3)| =  |D_3|$ (this can be done "manually", by checking all the options where automorphism can send the generators of $D_3$).

Since $Z(D_3) = \{e\}$, every automorphism of $D_3$ is inner. $H \le G$, therefore $G/K \cong Aut(D_3)$, with $|K| = \dfrac{|G|}{|H|}$.

Since $Z(H) = \{e\} =>$  $K \cap H = \{e\}$.

$|HK| = \dfrac{|H|\times|K|}{|H \cap K|} = |G|,$ hence $HK = G$.

Then you can use the proof outlined here:

[Direct product of two normal subgroups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690951/direct-product-of-two-normal-subgroups)