# Center and derived of the subgroup generated by $\langle(1,2,3),(1,2,4),(5,6)\rangle$ in $S_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Given the following subgroup of $S_6$: $G=\langle(1,2,3),(1,2,4),(5,6)\rangle$ I'm asked to show that $H= \langle (1,2,3),(1,2,4)\rangle$ is normal on G and isomorphic to $A_4$ and also to find the order, center and derived/commutator subgroup of G.

I think I got the first part right: since (5,6) is disjoint with the other two it commutes with them, so I can easily see that conjugating H with any element of G stays in H. Also, H generates all the 3-cycles that move $(1,2,3,4)$, so $H=A_4$ (http://people.math.gatech.edu/~ecroot/3cycle.pdf)

I'm having trouble with the rest. By Lagrange's theorem I know $12 \mid |G| \mid 720=|S_6| $, but I don't know the exact value.

I have also found that $(5,6)\in Z(G)$ since it commutes with the 3 generators, but I don't know whether there are more elements in Z(G) and I don't know how to find the derived.

Comment: Use `$\langle X\rangle$` for $\langle X\rangle$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're off to a good start:

> Since $(5\ 6)$ is disjoint with the other two it commutes with them, so I can easily see that conjugating $H$ with any element of $G$ stays in $H$.

Great, so indeed $H$ is normal in $G$.

> Also, $H$ generates all the $3$-cycles that move $(1\ 2\ 3\ 4)$...

You might want to substantiate this claim, depending on what you have seen or shown so far, of course. Then it does follow that $H\cong A_4$. From here it is not hard to prove that 
$$G=H\times\langle(5\ 6)\rangle\cong A_4\times S_2,$$
see also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690951/direct-product-of-two-normal-subgroups). With this characterization of $G$, finding the order, center and commutator subgroup of $G$ is a matter of finding the orders, centers and commutator subgroups of $A_4$ and $S_2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So the order would be $|A_4|*|S_2|=24$ (https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Order_of_semidirect_product_is_product_of_orders), the center would be just (5,6) as the center of $A_4$ is trivial and the derived would be the Klein 4-group V X (5,6), am I correct?

Comment: @Mipeal My pleasure, and yes, your answers seem correct. Feel free to accept and/or upvote. This also removes the question from the 'unanswered questions' queue.